# Executable app deployed using pyinstaller not working

Tags: python, pyqt, executable, py2exe, pyinstaller

So I've created a very simple python application using PyQt, the script works fine when I run it in python shell (spyder) (python 3.5).
When I tried to deploy my app to an executable file, I used pyinstaller (version 3.2) with the command : pyinstaller --onedir --onefile --name=APP --windowed "C:\directory\of\my.py file"
I don't get any specific errors in the command prompt and a file named dist is created containing the app.exe file.

when I run this .exe file I get a message box 'fatal error' saying that it failed to execute the script app.

I should mention that I used to have a TypeError in the bindepend.py file in pyinstaller but I already fixed it.

I hope someone has an answer for this.

Comment: Just a little update, I actually got some application to work with pyinstaller, but I still have a problem with application containing resources files (resource_rc.py). When I run it in debug mode I get this importerror : site-packages\PyQt4\uic\__init__ in LoadUiType importerror no module named 'resource_rc'